# What does 'agreed' modify in the sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> De Soto argues that, within many of the extralegal markets of the developing world, mutually **agreed** upon rules for distributing assets and recognizing property rights already exist.

I don't understand what 'agreed' modifies in the sentence, and what is the verb in the 'that' clause, which is the object of the verb 'argues'.

Comment: *mutually agreed upon* modifies *rules...*, which is the subject of the main-clause verb *exist*. DeSoto argues that these rules already exist.

Comment: @StoneyB Thank you so much.
Could you tell me what is agreed upon rules in the sentence ?

Comment: rules upon which [some unspecified parties] have agreed

Comment: I take "agreed-upon" as a compound word (a verb-centred compound adjective) so it should be hyphenated: _De Soto argues that, within many of the extralegal markets of the developing world, mutually **agreed-upon** rules for distributing assets and recognizing property rights already exist._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You and I can **agree upon** something, for example, that I will pay you $10 if you can say the alphabet backwards perfectly, and that you will pay me $10 if you make a mistake when attempting to do so.

The price of $10 is **agreed upon**.

$10 is the **agreed upon** bet.

> I bet you can't say the alphabet backwards! I will pay you $10 if you can do it perfectly, and you pay me $10 if you make a mistake.

We could hyphenate it as **agreed-upon** to make it clearer that the two-word phrase is acting as a single adjectival unit, modifying the noun **bet**.

The past participle of the verb **agree** is used adjectivally, and the preposition accompanies it when forming the adjectival phrase.

> It was a **mutually agreed upon** bet.

The adverb **mutually** modifies the adjective.

We can do this with many verbs that have prepositions.

> You can **sit on** a chair.
>
> I was just sitting on one of these chairs. Which of these two chairs is the **sat-on** chair? Can you guess?
>   --I suppose it is the chair that has a warm seat-cushion.

Answer (score 1):

***Matrix clause***
Simple Subject: "De Soto"
Predicating Verb: "argues"
Direct Object: the entire content clause starting with "that"

***Content clause***
Simple Subject: "rules"
Predicating Verb:  "exist"

> De Soto argues that rules exist.

The rules in question are not random or abstract or all-inclusive.   De Soto proposes that a specific set of rules exists.   These *rules* have been *mutually agreed upon*.

As a matter of clear word choice, I would prefer to see "commonly agreed upon" to "mutually agreed upon".   I reserve "mutual" for reciprocal actions, and there's no suggestion of reciprocity in this sentence.

Another thing that these rules have in common is their purpose or their nature.   These are *rules for distributing assets and recognizing property rights*.

> De Soto argues that mutually-agreed-upon rules for distributing assets and recognizing property rights exist.

I imagine that the author, if not De Soto himself, wants to emphasize the contrast between these actual rules and any hypothetical or potential rules that might replace them.   These rules *already exist*.

> De Soto argues that mutually-agreed-upon rules for distributing assets and recognizing property rights already exist.

These rules don't exist in all contexts and under all conditions.   Their existence has a limited scope.   They *exist within many of the extralegal markets of the developing world*.

> De Soto argues that mutually-agreed-upon rules for distributing assets and recognizing property rights already exist within many of the extralegal markets of the developing world.

The limits of this scope are important.   We can treat the adverbial prepositional phrase as a parenthetical or introductory phrase for its clause, granting it greater emphasis:

> De Soto argues that, within many of the extralegal markets of the developing world, mutually-agreed-upon rules for distributing assets and recognizing property rights already exist.

With the roles of all these modifiers clearly identified, the remaining parts of the sentence have clear relationships:

> **De Soto argues that**, within many of the extralegal markets of the developing world, mutually-agreed-upon **rules** for distributing assets and recognizing property rights already **exist**.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, I would vehemently argue to include a hyphen whenever using a "two-word phrase [that] is acting as a single adjectival unit" (from Tᴚoɯɐuo's answer)

This would include the particular case of "mutually agreed-upon"

The rationale for this is completely for coherence: As a reader, it is much easier to digest the sentence when the two-word phrase is syntactically linked. This is *especially* true in the (common) case where the second word is prepositional ("upon"), which can cause a jarring break in comprehension (if not complete confusion) if left otherwise standing alone.

Source: Am a native, fluent English speaker living in the Northeastern US my entire life and consider myself not only well-read but articulate. :)